# How to test spring rest controllers while mocking third party APIs?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockserver

I want to write an integration test for a rest controller that calls third party apis. For mocking the third party api I am using [mock-server java library](https://www.baeldung.com/mockserver) and for integration tests I am using test containers. It seems both of these are clashing. Mock-server library requires the test case to be annotated with `org.junit.test` while test containers require the test case to be annotated with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

If I use the jupiter test annotation that start up fails with `org.mockserver.client.SocketConnectionException: Unable to connect to socket /127.0.0.1:1080` while if I use the junit test annotation the test start up fails with `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started`

Has anyone come across this situation where you want to write rest controller tests along with mocking third party apis?
Thanks.

Comment: Both libs can be used and started without the Test annotations.
There is also the possiblity to just use the Spring Test classes like MockRestServiceServer, if you are calling the 3d party API via a RestTemplate.

Could you add a minimal version of you RestController and what it does, so it is easier to suggest a solution.  But yes there should be some sources out there how to write such tests.

Comment: I use apache httpclient to call third party apis (not restTemplate).The RestController implementation is slightly complex since it calls multiple classes and methods. I will try to create a minimal version out of it and edit the post. I didn't follow what you mean by starting the junit tests without the test annotation. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You can use wiremock without the Junit Rule and managing the lifecycle by your self (because of your comment with requiring org.junit.test). But best would be to a have an example Controller and Test what you want to achive.

WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8089));
wireMockServer.start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get my tests running by removing any annotations under the package `org.junit`. All annotations are from `org.junit.jupitor`.